# OSMNX does not return graph for all European capitals

Tags: python, openstreetmap, osmnx, nominatim

I am confused by the fact that some European capitals do not return a graph when queried with `osmnx`. It works perfectly for Lisbon, Berlin, Paris, etc., but when I try to run it with Brussels or Athens, I get a `NetworkXPointlessConcept: Connectivity is undefined for the null graph.` error.

I don't think this is expected and would appreciate any help if someone knows how to solve this.
I already checked the docs and ensured that all packages are up to date (`osmnx` is 1.1.1).

```
import osmnx as ox

# Does *NOT* work
ox.graph_from_place("Brussels, Belgium")

# Does *NOT* work
ox.graph_from_place("Athens, Greece")

# Works
ox.graph_from_place("Berlin, Germany")

# Works
ox.graph_from_place("Zurich, Switzerland")
```

Comment: Not a proper solution yet, but have you taken a look at https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/issues/8 ? It seems to be related (although a bit old)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know the reason why it cannot be obtained. When I looked into it, I was able to get geopandas, and from there I was able to get the latitude and longitude information.

```
import osmnx as ox

%matplotlib inline
ox.config(log_console=True)
ox.__version__

gdf = ox.geocode_to_gdf("Brussels, Belgium")

gdf
geometry    bbox_north  bbox_south  bbox_east   bbox_west   place_id    osm_type    osm_id  lat     lon     display_name    class   type    importance
0   POLYGON ((4.35895 50.84385, 4.35896 50.84385, ...   50.844296   50.843082   4.3605  4.358953    258572709   relation    3299877     50.843735   4.359779    Centre for Fine Arts, Brussels, 23, Rue Ravens...   amenity     arts_centre     0.634996

# lat, lon
G = ox.graph_from_point((50.84375, 4.359779), network_type='all_private')
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(G)
```

[image]

```
gdf = ox.geocode_to_gdf("Athens, Greece")
G = ox.graph_from_point((37.992907, 23.720079), network_type='drive')
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(G)
```

[image]

**graph.graph_from_place**

> Create graph from OSM within the boundaries of some geocodable place(s).

> The query must be geocodable and OSM must have polygon boundaries for the geocode result. If OSM does not have a polygon for this place, you can instead get its street network using the graph_from_address function, which geocodes the place name to a point and gets the network within some distance of that point.

> If OSM does have polygon boundaries for this place but you’re not finding it, try to vary the query string, pass in a structured query dict, or vary the which_result argument to use a different geocode result. If you know the OSM ID of the place, you can retrieve its boundary polygon using the geocode_to_gdf function, then pass it to the graph_from_polygon function.

Comment: This is the first experience I've used with your question, so please point out if the answer is off the mark.

Comment: You have been asked a question with a bounty on your head, and the granting period has ended. Do you accept the answer, or do you have a reason not to accept it, or do you need some action?

Comment: Sorry, was on vacation. The answer is not answering my questions that well, but helped to make a step forward/build a workaround solution. Thanks! Did you receive the bounty or how can I send it to you?

Comment: I did not receive a bounty. It will only be paid out if your answer is not accepted during the period. It is also possible to attach a [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty), but it must be at least one day long. If you like any of my other answers, you can vote for it. I will leave it up to you to decide which one to vote for, including not doing anything.